# Allow MySQL user with limited database access to create more users with similar access

Tags: mysql

I know that I can create a user with the `create user` privileges like so:

```
create user primary_user identified by 'pass';
grant all on *.* to primary_user with grant option;
```

This will in turn allow me to create users whilst logged in with `primary_user`.

Now let's assume I have a subset of databases, all with prefix `abc_`, and that I want my `primary_user` to only be able to access these databases.

Then the `grant` query above would look like so:

```
grant all on `abc_%`.* to `primary_user` with grant option;
```

The problem now, however, is that when I log in with my `primary_user` and try to create a `secondary_user`, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the
>   CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

**TL;DR**

Basically what I want is `primary_user` to only be able to access databases with the `abc_` prefix, and to also be able to create secondary users that in turn also only have access to databases with an `abc_` prefix.

Is this possible? Or is my only option to create the secondary users with a user account that has `create user` privileges on `*.*`?

Comment: I hope not. Seems like a hacker's dream - get in; create some new accounts; get out; come back in with the new accounts to cover the tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html):

> To use CREATE USER, you must have the global CREATE USER privilege or
>   the INSERT privilege for the mysql database.

Thus, users with privileges in specific databases cannot create users. Ofcourse, since you have `with grant option`, your primary_user can grant all database level privileges to other already created users (for the abc_ databases).

Note #1: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#idm139954830585520) you can find an interesting table with the various privileges and the different levels that they can be granted.

Note #2: Be extra cautious when giving GRANT OPTIONS to non-admin users because they can modify the privileges of other users which can lead to **chaos**. The [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_MySQL_Security#Privileges) states:

> *[Grant privilege]*... should be appropriately restricted to the DBA and Data (Table)
>   owners.  Give specific permissions on an as needed basis and use
>   different logins for different purposes.

Comment: @kosta-kontos Did this answer your question or do you require any further information?

Comment: Thanks it did. Only back online today :)